# Javascript clearing a frame

Tags: javascript

I am using a frameset with 3 frames, using parent.error.document.write("hi") I wrote to one of the frames but I want to clear it from another frame. Is it possible to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code I can only guess possible reasons.

1. You have `id`s in `<frame>`s instead of `name`s.
2. You've created content to the target frame using `document.write()` already, without `document.close()`. In this case the document is not cleared when writing again.
3. Document in target frame has been loaded from different domain.

If there's nothing to repair according the list above, you can try to refer `frameTwo`-document with `top.window.frameTwo.document`, or `top.window.frames['frameTwo'].document`.

Comment: thanks Teemu, will try with document.close(). It was removed by me, do you mean that this will erase all the stuff written to previously.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_methods.asp : I think this is what you were talking about.

Comment: Actually I meant this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write . If you write to document with `document.write()` without using `document.close()` after done so, the document stays open and doesn't use `open()` when you write later to the document. This way it's not cleared. If you've embedded `write()` in HTML, `</body>` (or end of parsing) will close document automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer it was sufficient for me to get out of this issue.Please tell me as to how one can go about and be proficient in Javascripting and html?

Answer (score 0):

Say your two frames are like so:

```
<frameset framespacing="0" rows="*"> 
       <frame name="frameOne" src="frame1.html">
       <frame name="frameTwo" src="frame2.html">
</frameset>
```

From inside frameOne you should be able to access frameTwo by:

```
window.parent.frameTwo.document
```

Comment: thank you Jivings,but window.parent.frameTwo.document.clear() is not working, actually my issue was with clearing the content of frame2 which was written as window.parent.frameTwo.document.write("this is frame 2")